# Algoliasearch not working with Angular Universal SSR when attempting to serve

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, algolia, angular-universal

### Issue

When attempting to serve my Angular Universal after a successful build with the command

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

Angular Universal SSR with Algoliasearch gives me the respond

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\node_modules\instantsearch.js\es\index.js:2
import algoliasearchHelper from 'algoliasearch-helper';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at algoliasearchProxy__default (C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\node_modules\angular-instantsearch\bundles\angular-instantsearch.umd.js:2:170)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Documents\Project\node_modules\angular-instantsearch\bundles\angular-instantsearch.umd.js:5:2)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
```

### Attempt

I followed the guide at https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/ 
When using the `npm run build:ssr` command everything builds perfectly. However it gives me the error above when trying to use the serve command.

After days of research I understand that it might be some compiling issues. However having looked everywhere on GitHub and numerous different sources I am unable to find any solution which solves this. This seems to be a more widespread issue than just Algolia and instantsearch.

I have attempted to update all packages to latest and specific versions, however it did not solve my serving issue either. I need to have the algolia package installed, so I am in need of a workaround of any kind.

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "operation-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "npm run compile_@agm_core",
    "compile_@agm_core": "babel node_modules/@agm/core -d node_modules/@agm/core --presets @babel/preset-env",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run operation-angular:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/operation-angular/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run operation-angular:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run operation-angular:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "@ngx-meta/core": "^8.0.2",
    "angular-gridster": "^0.13.14",
    "angular-gridster2": "^7.2.0",
    "angular-instantsearch": "^2.2.2",
    "angular-medium-editor": "^4.0.0-alpha",
    "angularfire": "^2.3.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "assign-deep": "^1.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "dsmorse-gridster": "^0.8.0",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery-touchswipe": "^1.6.19",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
    "medium-editor": "^5.23.3",
    "medium-editor-insert-plugin": "^2.5.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^8.0.4",
    "ngx-medium-editor": "^0.4.1",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "set-value": "^3.0.1",
    "sharp": "^0.23.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "tslib": "^1.11.0",
    "update": "^0.7.4",
    "videogular2": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.25",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.2",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^13.7.4",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "3.7.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your package.json file?

Comment: @bjdose Package.json has been edited into the question now, thanks for reply!

Comment: Did you add some code similar to `(window as any).process` into your `src/pollyfills.ts`?

Comment: I found an issue on Agolia GitHub page relative to your issue, indeed is the same error, try the solutions that they exposed: https://github.com/algolia/angular-instantsearch/issues/687#issuecomment-538274667

Comment: @bjdose I have the code you typed in my src/pollyfills.ts. I am pretty sure that the new angular universal at https://angular.io/guide/universal does not include a `webpack.server.config.js` however I shall attempt to see if it might be a solution but i have my doubts, however it is indeed the same issue. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: You're welcome, I think angular-instantsearch is not compatible with Angular Universal 9 yet. However, I'm using algoliasearch@3.32.0 and instantsearch.js@3.1.1 but with a module created by myself, very simple to do a search with a prediction list. I'm currently using Angular Universal 9 and works like a charm!